# Get stored procedures using SchemaCrawler

Tags: sql-server, schemacrawler

When I try to retrieve stored procedures from an SQL Server database using the SchemaCrawler API, I get this error:

```
12:28:07.427 [main] INFO  schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler - Retrieving routines
12:28:07.767 [main] WARN  schemacrawler.crawl.RoutineRetriever - JDBC driver does not support retrieving functions
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsDatabaseMetaData.getFunctions(JtdsDatabaseMetaData.java:3570) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at schemacrawler.crawl.RoutineRetriever.retrieveFunctions(RoutineRetriever.java:175) ~[schemacrawler-14.02.02.jar:na]
    at schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler.crawlRoutines(SchemaCrawler.java:214) [schemacrawler-14.02.02.jar:na]
    at schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler.crawl(SchemaCrawler.java:564) [schemacrawler-14.02.02.jar:na]
    at schemacrawler.utility.SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(SchemaCrawlerUtility.java:49) [schemacrawler-14.02.02.jar:na]
    at schemacrawler.utility.SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(SchemaCrawlerUtility.java:57) [schemacrawler-14.02.02.jar:na]
    at com.expedia.cgs.db.ExportScripts.main(ExportScripts.java:41) [classes/:na]
```

The jtds driver supports `DatabaseMetaData.getProcedures()` but not `DatabaseMetaData.getFunctions()`. Is there a workaround?

**UPDATE**: Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler;
import schemacrawler.schema.Catalog;
import schemacrawler.schema.Column;
import schemacrawler.schema.Routine;
import schemacrawler.schema.Schema;
import schemacrawler.schema.Table;
import schemacrawler.schema.View;
import schemacrawler.schemacrawler.DatabaseConnectionOptions;
import schemacrawler.schemacrawler.RegularExpressionInclusionRule;
import schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaCrawlerException;
import schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaCrawlerOptions;
import schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaInfoLevelBuilder;
import schemacrawler.utility.SchemaCrawlerUtility;

public class ExportScripts {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchemaCrawlerException, SQLException {
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();

        // Create a database connection
        final DataSource dataSource = new DatabaseConnectionOptions("jdbc:sqlserver://myDatabase;appName=SchemaCrawler;useCursors=true");
        final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection("username", "password");

        // Create the options
        final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
        // Set what details are required in the schema - this affects the
        // time taken to crawl the schema
        options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.standard());
        options.setRoutineInclusionRule(new RegularExpressionInclusionRule("ContentGeneration\\.dbo.*"));
        options.setSchemaInclusionRule(new RegularExpressionInclusionRule("ContentGeneration\\.dbo.*"));

        // Get the schema definition
        final Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection,
                options);

        for (final Schema schema : catalog.getSchemas()) {
            System.out.println(schema);
            for (final Routine routine : catalog.getRoutines()) {
                System.out.println("r--> " + routine);
                System.out.println("definition: " + routine.getDefinition());
            }
            for (final Table table : catalog.getTables(schema)) {
                System.out.print("o--> " + table);
                if (table instanceof View) {
                    System.out.println(" (VIEW)");
                } else {
                    System.out.println();
                }

                for (final Column column : table.getColumns()) {
                    System.out.println("     o--> " + column + " ("
                            + column.getColumnDataType() + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Send a query instead of using SchemaCrawler, like `SELECT o.name, m.definition FROM sys.objects INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules...`

Comment: @AaronBertrand That worked, but I had to modify your query to `SELECT o.name, m.definition
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m
ON m.object_id=o.object_id`. That said, can we make SchemaCrawler do this? Or does this functionality not exist?

Comment: Yeah my comment was just meant to be a general idea, not working code. And I have no idea about SchemaCrawler. I find that most helpers like this tend to get the simple stuff right, but fall apart whenever you need something exotic (and I hesitate to call functions exotic).

Comment: You can make SchemaCrawler use this query. Take a look at http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/INFORMATION_SCHEMA.html

Comment: Also, please provide more details, such as the command-line you are using.

Comment: @SualehFatehi I am using the API, not command-line options. As such, I don't think that it makes sense to use `schemacrawler.config.properties`. How do I do this from the API?

Comment: This functionality is built into SchemaCrawler, for SQL Server. Please post your code.

Comment: @SualehFatehi I have updated the question with my code. Please note that I am using schemacrawler from Maven, not a SQL-Server specific package (if such a thing exists).

Comment: Create a Config object, with host, database, username and password properties set. Then, use SqlServerDatabaseConnector.getDatabaseSystemConnector().newDatabaseConnectionOptions(Config) to obtain a connection. This will plugin to SchemaCrawler SQL Server functionality. In Maven, include http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cus.fatehi%7Cschemacrawler-sqlserver%7C14.02.02%7Cjar

Comment: @SualehFatehi Please post a formal answer containing example code for doing this. I am trying to get it working in parallel but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get full SchemaCrawler support for Microsoft SQL Server.

1. Include the SchemaCrawler jar that has Microsoft SQL Server support, in your Maven project.

`<dependency>
    <groupId>us.fatehi</groupId>
    <artifactId>schemacrawler-sqlserver</artifactId>
    <version>14.02.02</version>
</dependency>`

2. Use code similar that this below.

   final DatabaseSystemConnector dbSystemConnector = new SqlServerDatabaseConnector().getDatabaseSystemConnector();

   final DatabaseSpecificOverrideOptions databaseSpecificOverrideOptions = dbSystemConnector.getDatabaseSpecificOverrideOptionsBuilder().toOptions();

   final SchemaCrawlerOptions schemaCrawlerOptions = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
   schemaCrawlerOptions.setSchemaInfoLevel(InfoLevel.maximum.buildSchemaInfoLevel());

   final Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(getConnection(), databaseSpecificOverrideOptions, schemaCrawlerOptions);
3. Loop over the routines, and use `Routine.getDefinition()` to get the definitions.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/)

Comment: In the next version of SchemaCrawler, you will simply need to do:

        final Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, "sqlserver",
                options);

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still get the `AbstractMethodError` and `Routine.getDefinition()` is empty.

Comment: The AbstractMethodError is a warning. Let me try to reproduce your situation, and see why the definitions are not being populated.